# xrandr: jail mouse

Tags: mouse, jail, xrandr

I already asked this questions over at Ask Ubunutu. Unfortunately I have not received an answer. As this question is not Ubunutu specific, I am trying it here.

I am using xrandr via console to enable/disable secondary monitors. This work fine so far. Unfortuantely if I move my mouse beyond one screen, it appears on the other one. How can I disable this feature - and lock the mouse to one screen?

I use Ubunutu 10.10 and awesome - no gnome/kde.

Comment: for reference, link to askubuntu question: http://askubuntu.com/q/28062/45947

Answer (score 0):

I've never seen anything in the Xrandr or Xinerama docs about restricting mouse movement to a single monitor.

And, before Xinerama, I used to run [multiple X screens](http://idlastro.gsfc.nasa.gov/idl_html_help/UNIX_Multi-Monitor_Configurations.html) on multiple monitors, but the mouse moved freely between the monitors without trouble. (Windows were stuck on the monitor they started on; it worked much better than it sounds. :) So that's probably out.

You may be able to solve this starting another X server. Configure the second X11 for the correct screen, no mouse (keyboard too?) input device, and start clients on that second X server using `DISPLAY=:1 xterm &` and so forth.